# Asus zenfone 6 E:failed to mount/ cache

Tags: boot-loop, boot, unbricking, cache, asus-zenfone-5

Phone stucks on boot loading.

wipe data/factory reset  gives 
E:failed to mount/ cache error

wipe cache partition 
also fails.

abd sideload also give
E:failed to mount/ cache
Can't open vs..

Many same post suggest TWRP but i don't have it. Did not understand how to install it on a phone can't open.

Many more says EMMC chip is dead. I hope it is not. I know it is very likely but i want to try other options first if i can.

Comment: `fastboot flashing get_unlock_ability`

Comment: My old platform-tools fastboot did not have that command.
İnstalled yours, phone says "Result:FAIL (unknown command)".
My phone is from 2015

Comment: with locked bootloader you can only try to flash cache.img from [EDL mode](https://github.com/programmer-collection/zte/blob/master/README.md) (Qualcomm) or from [Intel Flash Tool](https://androidmtk.com/flash-stock-rom-using-intel-phone-flash-tool) (Intel Atom) https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2839984

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think EMMC chip is dead. only fastboot commands working.

Sometimes you need to accept inevitable.

Comment: I can't accept my answer sorry about that.

Comment: You can accept after 48 hours!