# Can baking EMMC chip revive a dead motherboard?

Tags: cache

I think my phones EMMC chip is dead. 
At my days i baked some dead graphic cards and get somewhat good results.

Can same thing work with EMMC chip on a phone?

If you never heard of it here a link.

https://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-repair-your-Graphics-Card-by-baking-it/

My original problem here if you are curious.[Asus zenfone 6 E:failed to mount/ cache](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/225291/asus-zenfone-6-efailed-to-mount-cache)

Comment: I don't think a GPU is comparable to a EMMC chip. The GPU creates a lot of heat which can affect it's soldering (many cycles of heating and cooling). The EMMC chip however does not heat up that much because it is optimized for power saving. On the other hand if the phone is already dead what can you lose?

Comment: Usually eMMCs die because their E/P cycles limit is reached and semiconductor cells can no more be charged/discharged. That can no way be fixed by heat treatment.

Comment: How to fix your video graphics card - the mothers way! Lol, will try with broken GeForce 9 today :)

Comment: @alecxs Try only if you are going to get rid of the card. This has a very low chance to work and even if it works results are not permanent. Usually card dies  again after a couple months. Also this will make your oven smell bad.  
I do not recommend doing this.

Comment: didn't work, some capacitors was exploding. i think it heated up too fast

Comment: @alecxs what was your oven degree? I did this with 200 C with no problem about exploding caps. Please don't tell me you used a microwawe.

Comment: lol of course not :D i did with 170 degree celsius for 10 minutes. no problem the card was 100% dead already before